# Simplify Build Process of Android Platform Apps

Tags: android, eclipse, build, intellij-idea, android-source

I'm working on a custom default android browser. I follow steps here [AOSP](http://source.android.com/source/building-running.html) to build my custom browser:

1. Clone android source code
2. Make changes on android browser
3. Build the Browser only for Nexus 4:

> ```
> lunch full_mako-eng
> make -j Browser
> ```

I rooted my Nexus 4 and install the Browser App. Everything is fine but I wonder if there is any other methods that simplier than above steps?
Can we just import the Browser into Eclipse or IntelliJ and build it directly to the phone?

Answer (score 0):

At first, I want to point to some errors in your receipt.
Command `make -jN` builds all the sources of AOSP, where N is usually equal to "number of processor cores + 2". After the whole build of sources you can just build your browser application using command `mmm packages/apps/Browser -jN snod`

Browser application is a part of Android and thus, it is possible that it uses some system permissions that are not available for applications that are not installed on system image or not signed with system image. If it is not, then you can extract Browser application from AOSP, import it as a separate application into Eclipse and build it as a separate application (however, you will need to modify some resources).